# Using Nettuts resource for CSS navigation; bottom shadow goes away if the parent has child elements

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to adapt a solution I found on Nettuts for my own needs. Overall it's working pretty well, except I'm experiencing some odd behavior when hovering over a top-level nav element that has a sub navigation—the shadow below that particular element goes away & doesn't come back. The Nettuts resource can be found [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-drop-down-nav-menu-with-html5-css3-and-jquery/).

Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class='navbar'>
      <div class='content'>
        <nav id='topNav'>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class='nav home' href='/' title='Home'>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class='parent'>
              <a class='nav about' href='/about' title='About'>About</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href='/about' title='History'>History</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href='/leadership' title='Leadership'>Leadership</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href='/directors' title='Directors'>Directors</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href='/science_advisory_board' title='Scientific Advisory Board'>Scientific Advisory Board</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href='/mission_statement' title='Acetylon Mission'>Acetylon Mission</a>
                </li>
                <li class='last'>
                  <a href='/careers' title='Careers'>Careers</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .no-js nav li:hover ul { display: block; }

div.container { width: 100%; }
div.navbar { background: url("/images/navbar_bg.jpg") repeat-x scroll center top transparent; border: medium none; box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #555555; height: 44px; width: 100%; }

nav { font: 1.4em 'myriad-pro', sans-serif; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; width: 978px; z-index: 1; height: 0; }
nav ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
nav li { position: relative; display: inline-block; list-style-type: none; margin-bottom: 0; }
nav li br { display: block; line-height: .4em; }
nav li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
nav li.last a { border-right: none; }
nav li a { display: inline-block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'myriad-pro', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 15px; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; width: 130px; vertical-align: bottom; padding: 0 16px 0 22px; }
nav li a:focus { outline: none; text-decoration: underline; }
nav li a.nav { word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 3.1em; height: 3.1em; }
nav li a.center { line-height: 1em; height: 3.1em; }
nav li a.nav:hover, nav li a.center:hover { background: url("/images/navbar_hover_bg.jpg") top center repeat-x; border: none; }
nav li a.center:hover { background: url("/images/navbar_hover_bg.jpg") top center repeat-x; border: none; }
nav li a.home { width: 64px; text-align: center; }
nav li a.about { width: 121px; }
nav ul:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }
nav a span { display: block; float: right; margin-left: 5px; }
nav ul ul { display: none; width: auto; position: absolute; left: 0; background: #E6F1F8; width: 180px; padding-bottom: 10px; }
nav ul ul li { float: none; display: block; }
nav ul ul a { margin-top: 11px; padding: 0 10px; border-left: none; border-right: none; font-size: .8em; color: #606062; line-height: 1em; }
nav ul ul a:hover { color: #004d9d; }
```

And the JS

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
var nav = $("#topNav");
//add indicator and hovers to submenu parents
nav.find("li").each(function() {

  if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {
    $("<span>").appendTo($(this).children(":first"));
    $("<li><hr style='width: 90%; color: #606062;' /></li>").appendTo($(this).find('li:not(:last-child)'));

    //show subnav on hover
    $(this).hover(
      function() {
        $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideDown();
        $($(this).closest('.parent').children()[0]).css('background', 'url("/images/navbar_hover_bg.jpg") top center repeat-x');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).find("ul").stop(true, true).slideUp();
        $($(this).closest('.parent').children()[0]).css('background', 'url("/images/navbar_bg.jpg") top center repeat-x');
      }
    );
  }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code was mostly fine; though I did clean it up quite a bit and make it considerably shorter. The real issue was that the hover image used didn't match the original in terms of height, so that caused the odd behavior. Lesson learned: beware of evil images.